# What property control how much you can extend a widget?

Tags: qt

When using a `QDockWidget`, there is a limit to how much you can extend the dock part. I would like to change this limit. Is there a way to do so?

For instance if there is a `QDockWidget` on the left and I use the mouse to increase its size horizontally, there is a point after which moving the mouse does not make the dock larger horizontically. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I would say the limit comes from the minimum size of your central widget: as this one refuses to be shrinked, docking bar cannot be nelarged. Did you try to change central widget's minimum size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of sizes here:

**1.** One is the size of your QDockWidget: See [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html) specially the Appearance section where it says:

> A QDockWidget acts as a wrapper for its child widget, set with setWidget(). Custom size hints, minimum and maximum sizes and size policies should be implemented in the child widget. QDockWidget will respect them, adjusting its own constraints to include the frame and title.

**2.** The other is where your QDockWidget is in. Normally you will have it inside another Widget, layout, etc. If you haven't declared any of this, try with `this()->getLayout()` and change its size/constraints

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, I did not consider that the other widget could be the problem, I will try this!